# Install masm without visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, masm

I have a windows 7 machine and I need masm on it for an assembly class, but I don't have visual studio, nor do I want it. I used it in a computer lab and hated it. I'm far more comfortable coding in just a regular text editor and compiling with cmd. Can I set up masm without needing to install visual studio, and if so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might come with some older SDK or Driver Kits (I pretty sure it doesn't come with the latest kits). In either case, you could install VS and still use MASM, the compiler, and other tools from the command line without ever launching the IDE. You even get a set of shortcuts to open a command window with the right environment settings to use the tools.

Comment: Download the MASM32 SDK http://www.masm32.com/ it contains ml and all the tools needed to assemble and link a program plus other goodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a 64-bit version of Windows:
http://www.fastshare.org/download/Masm64.exe
     or
http://rapidshare.com/files/324083249/Masm64.exe
     or
http://pliczek.net/index.php?p=23608
     (At the bottom is the button: "POBIERZ PLIK". I recommend this link.)

If you are using a 32-bit version of Windows:
http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm